# Plotting datetime output using matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, delimiter

So I have this code based on a simple data array that looks like this:

```
    5020 : 2015 7 11 11 42 54 782705
    5020 : 2015 7 11 11 44 55 575776
    5020 : 2015 7 11 11 46 56 560755
    5020 : 2015 7 11 11 48 57 104872
```

and the plot looks like the following:

```
    import scipy as sp
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    data = sp.genfromtxt("E:/Python/data.txt", delimiter=" : ")
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.title("Instagram")
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Followers")
    plt.xticks([w*2*60 for w in range(10)],
    ['2-minute interval %i'%w for w in range(10)])
    plt.autoscale(tight=True)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

I'm looking for a simple way to use the datetime output as x intervals on the graph, I can't figure out a way to make it understand it and there's this:

```
    In [15]:sp.sum(sp.isnan(y))
    Out[15]: 77
```

Which I guess is because of the spaces? I'm new to machine learning in Python, forgive my ignorance.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's because of the spaces. When you're importing the data it's assigning `NaN` to your x values.

Try this, it's a little longer but should work:

```
data = []
x=[]
y=[]

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.split(':'))

for i in data:
y.append(i[0])
x_old.append(i[1])

for t in x_old:
    x.append(float(t[17:19]+'.'+t[20:])/60+int(t[14:16]))
```

Because of the spaces I had to convert the data into float manually. I divided the seconds+milliseconds by 60 then added to minutes since I'm assuming you're only interested in that (2 min interval).

If the format is done better you can use `datetime` and extract the information better. For example:

```
my_time = datetime.strptime('2015 7 11 11 42 54.782705', '&Y &m %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: I tried this and got: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015 7 11 11 42 54 782705

EDIT: it's because of a non printable char '\n'

Comment: Ok then, I edited my post thinking it was another conversion factor. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by directly passing datetime.datetime objects to pyplot. Here is a short example:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# Note: please figure out yourself the data input
x     = [dt.datetime(2015,7,11,11,42,54),
     dt.datetime(2015,7,11,11,44,56),
     dt.datetime(2015,7,11,11,46,56),
     dt.datetime(2015,7,11,11,48,57)]

#define the x limit:
xstart= dt.datetime(2015,7,11,11,40,54)
xstop = dt.datetime(2015,7,11,11,50,54)


y     = [782705, 575776, 560755, 104872]

fig,ax= plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y)
xfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%D %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax.set_title("Instagram")
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Followers")
ax.set_xlim(xstart,xstop)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]